# Weird <li> height bug on Microsoft Edge with a "display: table" child element

Tags: html, css, html-lists, microsoft-edge

So I have this simple code which works perfectly on Chrome:

```css
.section-sub-desc-list {
    margin: 0px;
    font-weight: normal;
    list-style-type: square;
}

.display-table {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}

.display-table-cell {
    display: table-cell;
}

.time-interval {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 30%;
    text-align: right;
    font-style: italic;
    font-weight: normal;
}
```

```html
<ul class="section-sub-desc-list">
    <li>
        <div class="display-table">
            <div class="display-table-cell">
              B.S. Computer Science
            </div>
            <div class="time-interval">
              Oct 2010 - Jun 2014
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Clicking the run button shows the expected result, but this is how it renders on Edge: [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YajV0.jpg)

The problem is the extra height that is added on the "li" tag but I don't know what is the cause of that and how would I go about fixing it.

Comment: Have you tried @supports (-ms-ime-align:auto) to check for microsoft edge, then change the css? Or, put the same CSS into supports (-ms-ime-align:auto) I can't access edge right now, so I'm sorry I can't be of much help.

Comment: this rule does absolutely nothing for me :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I've been thinkering a little with the display property and I finally got it working on Edge as well.

This is the new code:

```css
.section-sub-desc-list {
  margin: 0px;
  font-weight: normal;
  list-style-type: square;
}

.display-table {
  display: inline-flex;
  width: 100%;
}

.display-table-cell {
  width: 100%;
}

.time-interval {
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-align: right;
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: normal;
}
```

```html
<ul class="section-sub-desc-list">
  <li>
    <div class="display-table">
      <div class="display-table-cell">B.S. Computer Science</div>
      <div class="time-interval">Oct 2010 - Jun 2014</div>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

**Some remarks**

- `display: inline-flex; width: 100%` on the wrapper div(*display-table*)
  is the same thing as just writing `display: flex`. Why did I use the
  inline-flex method? Because Edge still messes up the heights if I
  just use the `display: flex` property on the wrapper, for some unknown reason.
- Using `width: 100%` on the *B.S. Computer Science* text div does not make it fill up the whole row, because we are now working with flex items, since the parent(*display-table*) is a flex container. At least this is how I think flex items work.
- I have used the `white-space: nowrap` property on the time interval text because it would wrap around for reasons unknown